# Loading PDF from BLOB stream (MySQL/C#)

Tags: c#, pdf, file-permissions

I am using

- BLOBs in MySQL
- C# VS 2010
- PDF Reader Component ( added from C#) to
  display the PDF

I have an application that uses MySQL as backend and C# as front. i have added a PDF Reader component to my form and i wish to show the pdf on that form. the pdf can be accessed using the loadFile method of the component. My PDFs are stored as BLOBs in MySQL which i extract and copy it to the disk. I then link the path to the loadFile Argument to display my pdf..
This all works fine but now i would like to know if there is a way so that i can display the pdf (stored as a blob in MySQL) without copying it to the hard disk first.

Comment: What is that PDF component that you are using?

Comment: it is there in the C# add components toolbar axAcroPDF is the name

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reading it directly to a binary array and then sending it to the output?  Something along these lines should work.  Your equivalent data adapter would work in the first line.

```
        // Generate Report
        byte[] data = (byte[])dataTable.Rows[0]["BLOB"];

        // Present the generated PDF to the user
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", data.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(data);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
```

Comment: Why did you think there's a Response in the question? The talk seems to be about a desktop application.

Comment: this code that you have posted is for the web, right? i am developing an application. Also in my code i write all the data from the db to a byte array and then use filereader and binarywriter to write to the disk. i want to bypass writing to the disk and directly display the pdf in my AxAcroPDF component.